# Why is my flutter codes not executing on the android emulator

Tags: java, android, flutter

```
C:\Users\TomiwaPC>flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel dev, 2.1.0-12.1.pre, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.30], locale en-NG)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0-rc2)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
[√] Connected device (1 available)
• No issues found!
```

The android emulator is running fine but the flutter codes are not executed.

Under the android sdk
Android 10.0(Q)
I have
Android SDk Platform 29 installed
Sources for Android 29 installed
Android TV Intel x86 Atom System Image not installed
and others not installed
Could this be the problem

I am new to flutter and i am getting frustrated.
If you can provide your email so that i can send screenshot to you. I would be glad

Comment: post the output of `flutter build apk --v`

Comment: What do you mean flutter codes are not executed, does your app deploy to emulator with .. flutter run ?

Comment: C:\Users\TomiwaPC>flutter run
Error: No pubspec.yaml file found.
This command should be run from the root of your Flutter project.

Comment: flutter run should be performed from the app directory not globally. Also you can post the error image over here that would be useful.